# What Pools operate on port 80 or 443?

Tags: mining-pools, firewall

My firewall blocks all ports except 80 and 443.  Are there any pools that accept inbound connections on these ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure but you can find a complete list of pools here which should help https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Pool_Operators

Comment: I clicked on a few of them.  No ports are listed... perhaps someone will update it with current knowledge

Answer (score 3):

We ( https://wwww.bitlc.net ) primarily, and strongly recommend, use of port 80 mining. With 8080 and 8332 fallbacks, but only over IPv4...

The regular pool.bitlc.net:80 is fully accessible over both IPv4 and IPv6.
pool.bitlc.net:8080 and :8332 works to, both there is no reason to use them...

Answer (score 2):

BitMinter, hostname mint.bitminter.com on port 80 or 8332. You should also be able to mine over SSL on port 443 but you'll have to use bitminter.com as hostname or the certificate won't be valid.